# Are manifolds always surfaces in their ambient space, or can they be solid?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Sorry for my ignorance about differential topology, but I come from the statistics and ML world. There is a lot of discussion nowadays about data manifolds and such. I am familiar with manifolds more from my nonlinear differential equations days and from some experience with algebraic topology.

My question was very simple. Are manifolds, as they are described in topology, always surfaces--meaning that they don't have any intrinsic volume? Or can a manifold be a solid, as in a subspace of some ambient dimension?

In the ML and Bayesian statistics context, we are often thinking about the values of some random variables living on a manifold that represents the joint probability over those variables. Then we use sampling methods like MCMC or hamiltonian monte carlo to sample from that manifold. However, again, I was never sure whether that manifold could be solid or was it purely a surface?

In reading about manifolds I understand the formalisms about local Euclidean behavior, etc. But again I can't seem to resolve my question from the formalisms, unfortunately.

Thanks to the respondants who can resolve my ignorance here.

Comment: Certainly an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is an $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$; a closed ball is likewise a submanifold *with boundary*. Most often submanifolds we encounter have dimension less than that of the ambient space.

Comment: I will add the comment that you appear to be using the word "surface" — not specifically for a $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$ or $\Bbb R^n$ — but to signify a submanifold (in high dimensions) whose dimension is in fact less than the ambient dimension. (And you're certainly not worrying about abstract manifolds that appear without living in an ambient space to start with.)